# Apache http basic authentication?

Tags: apache, http

Is there some simple code that I can add to an `.htaccess` file or my virtual host file to enforce http basic auth?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this ?

```
AuthUserFile /my/derectory/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
AuthName "Secured Access"
AuthType Basic
```

the interesting part for you is `Require valid-user`

But if you can, please provide more informations about why you have you tried to do ^^

Comment: Thanks. Just have to use `htpasswd` to create the password file http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/htpasswd.html